# Is there a way to expand environment variables in *.ini files?

Tags: environment-variables

I have to work with an ini file, but I need a value set in the file to be based on an environment variable.  For example,

> ...
>   [program] dir=%SystemDrive%\SomeFolder\
>   ...

In this case, `SystemDrive` is an environment variable on the machine.  The software that reads this ini file is out of my control, but I can see from the error message I get that it read `dir` as `%SystemDrive%\SomeFolder\`, instead of the expanded version `C:\SomeFolder\`.

How do I (or is it possible to) get environment variables to expand when the ini file is read?  I don't have access to the code of the program that reads the ini file.  However, I'm hoping there is a proper syntax/technique for specifying an environment variable to be expanded.

Comment: Probably the only way to achieve this would be for you to write a program that replaced any such variables it found in the .ini file with their current values just before invoking the program that reads it.